# AWS Lambda: Invoking the endpoint I get a ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' error

Tags: python, csv, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, valueerror

I invoked the endpoint with the lambda handler as follows:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    json_event = json.dumps(event)
    request = json.loads(json_event)
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(request)
    dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True)
    payload = jojo_300_script(dataframe)
    payload=payload.replace('', np.nan, regex=True)

    print(payload)
    

    csv_file = io.StringIO()
    payload.to_csv(csv_file, sep=',', header =True, index=True, encoding='utf-8')
    my_payload_as_csv = csv_file.getvalue()
    
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName="kawa1",
                                       ContentType='text/csv',
                                       Body=my_payload_as_csv)
                                       
                                      
                                       
    print(response)
    
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
    
    print(result)
    
    return
```

I keep getting the ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' in the cloud watch management console and do not know how to fix this.
The json test data has to be added and adjusted with other data to be able to function as a input data for the model therefore a script is introduced to generate this data (Jojo_300_script) as seen above.

Comment: Please post the entire traceback. It probably contains the answer to your question.